# Bridging the gap from theory to implementation in "Conditional Distance Correlation" by Wang et al. 2015?

Tags: sample, matrix, conditional, partial-effect, distance-covariance

In an attempt to implement a form of conditional distance correlation for random variables represented as vectors of observations, I came upon [this](https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4749041/) paper that  nicely extends the notion of [distance correlation/covariance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation#Distance_covariance) to the conditional case, but am having some trouble figuring out how to implement this in practice/interpret some of the later parts of the paper where I think this becomes clear.

Specifically, in section 3, how to apply equation 5/6 in the case of 3 sets of observations, $X', Y', $ and $Z'$ respectively where each observation of $X', Y',$ and $Z'$ is an element of $p, q,$ or $r$-dimensional Euclidean space, respectively.

How do we evaluate the summation/the kernels at $Z$ in equations 5/6? since this looks like a similar summation to the one to determine the distance covariance in the Wikipedia article on distance correlation, but am unsure of how to empirically substitute here.

I am unsure if I provided enough context/what needs to be transcribed here from the paper and apologize if anything isn't up to requirement for a CV.SE post since I haven't asked a question like this before.